# What is the requirement for separable parameters in an LSQ fit?

Tags: parametric, signal-processing, curves, parameter-estimation

I am trying to determine the amplitude of an amplitude modulated sinus as accurate as possible. My sampling frequency is sufficently high. The entire model looks as follows:

$$ A*sin(2*pi*f_1*t+p_1)*sin(2*pi*f_2*t+p_2) + O + e(t) = y(t) $$

Where $e(t)$ is the error and $y(t)$ is my measured data.

[image]

I am interested in determining $A$ as good as possible, whilest I only know $f_1$ and $y(t)$.

Using the idea from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60500/how-to-find-a-good-fit-for-semi-sinusoidal-model-in-r), I can determine $A$ (and $p_1, O$) for the not modulated case. However this reduced model is of course less accurate:

$$ A*sin(2*pi*f_1*t+p_1) + O + e(t) = y(t) $$

This can be LSQ-fitted similiar to a LSQ-polynom-fit using this approach:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial Parameter} (A_1*sin(f_1*t)+A_2*cos(f_1*t)+O-y)^2 = 0 $$

I implemented this and it works fine (so the constant term (offset) is not a problem at all).

Now if want to use the accurate model what options do I have? Can I add another parameter to reduce the error for a **local** fit (for example multiply a low degree taylorpolynom to model the influence of the lower frequent sinus)?
What are the requirements for a new parameter to be separable? More general under what requirements can I orthogonalize parameters (for instance by using chebyshev polynomials)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. the number of parameters you can recover depends on the number and the rate of the samples, and on the independence between the parameters. what do you mean by reducing the error for a local fit ? a sine modulated by an other sine is also $\cos(x(\omega_1+\omega_2))+\cos(x(\omega_1-\omega_2))$. for recovering the frequencies and phases of a sum of complex exponentials there is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_signal_classification even if because of the noise the fourier transform is much more useful in real life

Comment: @user1952009 thx for you comment. There are enough samples (like 100 per period). The model - sin()*sin() - is correct in that form. With local fit I mean, that I only fit over half a periode of the higher frequent sinus. Thats also why I don't expect to be able to fit the whole product. What I want to know is what possible indepent parameters can I add. Or how in general the requirement for independency looks like (not how to show the independence of matrix columns, but what an independend parameter in the model must fullfill).

Comment: without any noise, independent is another word for injective, with noise it could become "sensitivity of the maximum likelihood estimator to noise",  and I still don't understand well your question

Comment: @user1952009 When I try to fit $ \frac{\partial}{\partial Parameter} (A_1*sin(f_1*t)+A_2*cos(f_1*t)+O-y)^2 = 0 $ analytically, I can separate the parameters and get the right result. I can separate $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial Parameter} ((A_1-D*t)*sin(f_1*t)+(A_2-D*t)*cos(f_1*t)+O-y)^2 = 0 $$ to a sum of only on one parameter dependend terms. But this fit does not give the right result. I want to understand the reason behind this, if there is any. Your comment about injective does, as far as I understand it, boil down to "have at least as many distinctive measurements as parameters".

Comment: Noise should not limit the number of parameters I am able to separate, but rather how good I can find them? Also can I determine if there is a way to orthogonalize parameters - e.g. is there a transform, which allows me to make my measurements distinctive for the new model?

Comment: if $\hat{\Theta} = f(y)$ is your parameter estimator where $y$ is your data, noise transforms $y$ into a random variable $Y$ so $f(Y)$ your parameter estimator also becomes a random variable $\implies$ noise completely changes the framework.

Comment: I thought that by using an LSQ fit and under the presence of noise, the target function would change, but it was reasonable to assume that the resulting parameters would still be the "best" fit for the original problem?

Comment: no, absolutely not. in your particular case, for your parameters to stay unchanged in the presence of noise you have to filter out any $f_1$ frequency component of the noise : replace $e(t)$ by $e \ast h(t)$ where $h$ is a filter which removes the $f_1$ frequency

Comment: This is a good point. However I am more concerned about the error caused by the modulation, since especially for a low combined amplitude in the picture above, I got a big change of maximum amplitude per high frequent period. Example can there exist a D such that $ \frac{\partial}{\partial Parameter} ((A_1-D*t)*sin(f_1*t)+(A_2-D*t)*cos(f_1*t)+O-y)^2 = 0 $ has only separable parameters given enough measurements? - I am sorry that I am unable to better phrase the question.